# Directive to avoid writeOut to ngModel [Angular]

Tags: javascript, angular, angular2-directives

I would like to create a directive that when it's given an variable with value of **TRUE** and if the user change the input value it won't write out that new value to the NgModel.

Example of use:
Directive selector: d-avoid-change

```
<input type="text" name="surname" 
    [(ngModel)]="model.surname" 
    [d-avoid-change]="true">
```

If the surname model that came from the server is "Foo" and the user change it to "Bar", the model.surname stays "Foo" and I can give a message to the user.

I was trying with another approach with the directive, that was to remove the input and click *EventListener* so the user would not be able to click, but that would seem like a bug.

I want to use it instead of the **disabled** property of HTML, because if I just use [disabled]="true" the user can open browser HTML inspector and change the value and save it, also I don't want to validate those permissions on the server. I've searched alot about this and couldn't find any suggestion, does anyone know how I could do that?

Comment: If you don't validate on the server, you will always be vulnerable. I can just use your API without your frontend.

Comment: @IngoBürk I know about that, the security should keep only at the server, we are validating everything from login to logout there, on our main application we have permissions based by roles, but this is a application for some specific kind of users, most old aged people, just want to make the directive to keep them from trying to 'cheat' on my disabled fields.

Comment: You think elderly people will edit the HTML? Man, those are some unusually tech-savvy people you're oldsters with then.

Comment: Not sure if that works, because I usually use reactive forms, but can't you just use one-way-binding `[ngModel]`?

Comment: @masterfloda gonna try that, thanks

Comment: @masterfloda Didn't worked, also our both applications use template-driven forms :/

Comment: I just tried it and it does work: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tzwyhc Try changing the value in the form field, you'll see that the model value does not change.

Comment: Yes, your experiment do work, but in my case, sometimes I need it to change, and sometimes I don't, based on a variable that changes depending on the profile of the user. I am gonna try the approach I was going in the start for now until I find another way to do it. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a way to build a directive that saves the original NgModel in a private variable and then if it receives the Input parameter as **TRUE** it will ignore the changing and put the original NgModel instead.

Also it overrides the native *disabled* so I don't need to use the directive and also the native *disabled*.

Directive code:

```
import {
    Directive,
    ElementRef,
    AfterViewInit,
    Input,
    AfterContentInit,
    ViewContainerRef,
    Renderer2
} from '@angular/core';
import { NgModel } from '@angular/forms';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';

declare let $;

@Directive({
    selector: '[d-disabled]',
    providers: [NgModel]
})
export class DisabledDirective implements AfterViewInit {

    @Input('d-disabled')
    set disabled(disabled: boolean) {
        if (disabled) {
            this.renderer.setAttribute(this.el.nativeElement, 'disabled', 'true');
        } else {
            this.renderer.removeAttribute(this.el.nativeElement, 'disabled');
        }
        this._disabled = disabled;
    }

    _disabled: boolean;
    originalModel: any;

    constructor(private el: ElementRef,
        private ngModel: NgModel,
        private renderer: Renderer2) {
        this.ngModel.valueAccessor.registerOnChange = this.registerOnChange;
        this.ngModel.valueAccessor.registerOnTouched = this.registerOnTouched;

        this.originalModel = this.ngModel;
    }

    ngAfterViewInit() {
        Observable.fromEvent(this.el.nativeElement, 'input')
            .map((n: any) => n.target.value)
            .subscribe(n => {
                if (this._disabled) {
                this.ngModel.viewToModelUpdate(this.originalModel.value);
                this.ngModel.control.patchValue(this.originalModel.value);
                this.ngModel.control.updateValueAndValidity({ emitEvent: true });
            } else {
                    this.onChangeCallback(n);
                }
            });
    }

    private onChangeCallback: (_: any) => void = (_) => { };

    private onTouchedCallback: () => void = () => { };

    registerOnChange = (fn: (_: any) => void): void => { this.onChangeCallback = fn; };
    registerOnTouched = (fn: () => void): void => { this.onTouchedCallback = fn; };

}
```

How to use it:

```
<input type="text" name="surname" 
    [(ngModel)]="model.surname" 
    [d-disabled]="true">
```

If anyone can help me to improve in any way this method, but this is working as I wanted.